# "error:expected ';' before '{' token

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm doing homework in C++ using code blocks. The task was to write a program that will determine if a number is odd or even. Code is below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int number;

int main()
{
   cout<<"Please enter number"<<endl;
   cin>>number;
   if(number%2==0)
   {
      cout<<"The number:"<<number<<" is even" <<endl;
   }
   else()
   {
      cout<<"The number:"<<number<<" is odd" <<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error that is displayed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `else()` in your code (above the return statement). `else` does not need parentheses after it. Also be aware that you probably don't need to have number as a global variable in this situation. If it MUST be global, do it, but otherwise try to keep your variables scoped in a class or function.